# Changing a derived field to float and getting the average of the derived field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe called `FP` with 13 columns, derived a new field called `price/sqm`, and dropped 10 columns.

```
FP['price/sqm'] = FP['price'] / FP['floor_area_sqm']
FP = FP.loc[:,['year', 'town', 'type', 'price/sqm']]
```

The dataframe has 700,000 rows and looks something like this:

```
   year   town    type     price/sqm
0  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    290.322581
1  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    193.548387
2  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    258.064516
3  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    193.548387
4  1990   AMK   3 ROOM    646.575342
5  1990   AMK   3 ROOM    686.567164
```

I'm trying to average `price/sqm` according to `['year','town','type']` using the code below but I get the `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

```
FP['avg_price/sqm'] = FP.groupby(['year', 'town', 'type'])['price/sqm'].aggregate(mean)
```

I have a similar code for a different dataframe which works so I'm not sure why its not working for this code. The other code is `gdp['yearly_gdp'] = gdp.groupby(['year'])['value'].transform(sum)`

I'm assuming its because `price/sqm` is a str and have tried the following codes to convert it to a float but I either get an error, or it still returns as str.

```
FP['price/sqm'] = float(FP['price/sqm'])
FP['price/sqm'] = FP['price/sqm'].astype(float)
FP['price/sqm'] = pd.to_numeric(FP['price/sqm'], errors = 'coerce')
FP[['price/sqm']] = FP[['price/sqm']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Can someone advise me how to fix this?

FP.dtypes:

```
   year   town    type     price/sqm
0  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    290.322581
1  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    193.548387
2  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    258.064516
3  1990   AMK   1 ROOM    193.548387
4  1990   AMK   3 ROOM    646.575342
5  1990   AMK   3 ROOM    686.567164
year        object
town        object
type        object
price/sqm   float64
dtype: object
```

df1.dtypes:

```
month               object
town                object
type                object
block               object
street_name         object
storey_range        object
floor_area_sqm      float64
flat_model          object
lease_commence_date int64
resale_price        int64
dtype:       object
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['year', 'town', 'type']).mean()` doesn't work then?

Comment: Or maybe you want `FP['avg_price/sqm'] = df.groupby(['year', 'town', 'type'])['price/sqm'].transform('mean')` ?

Comment: I get the same error for both methods

Comment: what does `FP.dtypes` show you - can you [edit] your question to include that?

Comment: If `FP['price/sqm'] = FP['price'] / FP['floor_area_sqm']` works - then `price/sqm` can't possibly be a string...

Comment: when i type `print(type('price/sqm'))` I get `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Okay... answer the first part of my comment first then, what does your DF show when you do `.dtypes` on it... the `/` wouldn't have worked with strings as in your example dataframe with the `price/sqm` showing as it is?

Comment: I've added the .dtypes in my question and it does show float..

Comment: Don't suppose you're trying to use an original DF where that's not computed and ends up as a result and another one you're trying to group by or something odd like that.

Comment: Can you how an example of the frame *before* you do `FP['price/sqm'] = FP['price'] / FP['floor_area_sqm']`.... - that seems to work? If so... you're probably using a wrong name or you've rebinded FP somehow?

Comment: I don't quite understand.. I'm reading in a csv file, derived the `price/sqm` field, and trying to group the average of `price/sqm` based on the existing fields. They are all coded on the same DF.

Comment: Okay... after the `pd.read_csv(...)` what does that `df.dtypes` show?

Comment: I've added the dtypes. its the same for df1 to df4

Comment: sorry, resale_price for df2 - df4 is float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you because you to transform the results according to indexing of dataframe

```
FP['avg_price/sqm'] = FP.groupby(['year', 'town', 'type'])['price/sqm'].transform(lambda x:x.mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`FP['avg_price/sqm'] = FP.groupby(['year', 'town', 'type'])['price/sqm'].mean()`

and:

`gdp['yearly_gdp'] = gdp.groupby(['year'])['value'].sum()`

you don't need to use `aggregate` or `transform`

If `price/sqm` is float, just transform it using:

`FP['price/sqm'].astype(float)`

I hope it solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried all those variations but get an error when I use FP.groupby

Comment: try `groupby(['year', 'town', 'type'], as_index=False)`